# Set cookie site

Tags: php, cookies

I have a script that i server to my clients. Now without going into details the script is looking if the user has a cookie from a certain domain (my domain) and if the user has the right cookie some data and features are given to the user.

Now for secruity reasons me and my company had to change our base url address of the place where cookie is set.

Now even though the above seems rather strange i can ensure you that my question is fairly simple:

Is it possible to change the url of a cookie and if so how?

Comment: If a cookie is set you can't change the URL afterwards. You have to delete it, and set it again with the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser only sends the cookies of the corresponding domain, so you have to create the cookies again, from a php script on the new domain.